# How do I generate wallets and transfer/mint tokens to them using python/solidity?

Tags: python, solidity, smartcontracts, bep20

I have made a simple bep 20 token and I am trying to mint my wallet address 50% of the token supply and evenly distribute the remaining 50% of the supply between 10 different wallets that I would like to generate with code. I am not sure whether this can be done within the contract itself or has to be done separately through python after the contract is deployed.

**here is the solidity code:**

````
contract Token {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    mapping(address => mapping(address => uint)) public allowance;
    uint public totalSupply = 10000000000;
    string public name = 'TestToken';
    string public symbol = 'TEST';
    uint public decimals = 9;
    
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    event Approval(address indexed owener, address indexed spender, uint value);
    
    constructor() {
        balances[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
    }

    function balanceOf(address owner) public view returns(uint) {
        return balances[owner];
    }
    
    function transfer(address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(msg.sender)>= value, 'You are broke lol');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[msg.sender] -= value;
        emit Transfer(msg.sender, to, value);
        return true;
        }
    
    function transferFrom(address from, address to, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        require(balanceOf(from) >= value, 'You broke');
        require(allowance[from][msg.sender] >= value, 'allowance too low');
        balances[to] += value;
        balances[from] -= value;
        emit Transfer(from, to, value);
        return true;
    }
    
    function approve(address spender, uint value) public returns(bool) {
        allowance[msg.sender][spender] = value;
        emit Approval(msg.sender, spender, value);
        return true;
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `mint()` function in a way that distributes the first 50% to the `msg.sender` (or a hardcoded address) and the other 50% to the 10 addresses that are passed in the function argument.

Your python script (or any other client, a wallet software, a JS script, etc.) than generates the 10 addresses and passes them in the argument. Example in JS using the [web3](https://web3js.readthedocs.io/en/v1.3.4/) library:

```
const Web3 = require('web3');

const web3 = new Web3(providerUrl); // TODO fill your value
const contract = new web3.eth.Contract(abiJson, contractAddress); // TODO fill your values

const mintTokens = async () {
    const amount = web3.utils.toWei('1', 'ether');
    const addresses = await getRandomAddresses();

    await contract.methods.mint(amount, addresses).send();
}

const getRandomAddresses = async () {
    let addresses = [];

    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        const account = web3.eth.accounts.create();
        addresses.push(account.address);
    }

    return addresses;
}

mintTokens();
```

Mind that this example requires the `_amount` to be divisible by 20. Otherwise, it would result in slightly incorrect results (up to 5% total).

Also, there's no authorization in my example, so anyone can execute this function. You'll probably want to implement an authorization as well (for example using the [ownable](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/access-control#ownership-and-ownable) pattern), or mark the function as `internal` (so that it's not executable by anyone) and call it just from the `constructor()`.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.4;

contract Token {
    mapping(address => uint) public balances;
    event Transfer(address indexed from, address indexed to, uint value);
    
    function mint(uint256 _amount, address[10] memory _receivers) external {
        // mint 50% of the _amount to one address
        balances[msg.sender] += _amount / 2;
        emit Transfer(address(0x0), msg.sender, _amount / 2);
        
        // mint the rest (another 50%) evenly to each receiver
        // i.e. each gets 5%
        for (uint i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            balances[_receivers[i]] += _amount / 20;
            emit Transfer(address(0x0), _receivers[i], _amount / 20);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! How do I go about doing this part 'Your python script (or any other client, a wallet software, a JS script, etc.) then generates the 10 addresses and passes them in the argument.' Also this is just a small side task that I was curious about doing so security shouldn't be a major problem.

Comment: @Reece I've added a JS example (cause I'm better in JS than in Python), hope it helps.

Comment: Appreciate it,  I'll try adapt it to python and see where I get with it

Comment: I couldnt get the web3.eth.accounts.create() to work so I instead used `from eth_account import Account` and the following code `addresses = [];
i = 0
while i < 10:
    acct = Account.create('KEYSMASH FJAFJKLDSKF7JKFDJ 1530')
    address = acct.address
    i += 1

contract.functions.mint(10000000000, addresses).call()`                                However I am not sure how to give the inputs for the token number and the addresses and keep getting the error `Function invocation failed due to no matching argument types`. Do you know how to sort this out?